# SQL Statement from VS2005 Reporting Services to SSMS

Tags: sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2005, ssms, reportingservices-2005

When I make a report in Reporting Services I would like a way to automatically fill in some of the report's configuration in my database.

For example I have a table 'parameter' and a table 'report', how can I automatically insert the parameters and report name, from the report I just created using VS2005, in my database?

I am looking to use/write a plugin or something like that, or is there a method that is a lot easier but that I am just overlooking?

Your help would be very much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your insert code inside a stored procedure and call it in your data tab. Make sure you have insert/update permissions for the sql user.

Hope it helps!